# How to map collection with arrays to collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection where in each document there's an array property. I want to return a new collection with documents all the inner elements of the arrays (in a sense - flatten the collection).

Example:

```
{
  ...
  some_list: [{
    name: "Lorem", age: 12
  }, {
    name: "Ipsum", age: 13
  }]
}, {
  ...
  some_list: [{
    name: "Ipsum22", age: 132
  }]
}
```

From which I want a collection with documents

```
{
  name: "Lorem", age: 12
}, {
  name: "Ipsum", age: 13
}, {
  name: "Ipsum22", age: 132
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to output a document for each element in `$some_list` and [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) to move the embedded document with `name` and `age` keys to the top level.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$some_list"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$some_list"
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UnyUcEOagEh)